# more like vs more

Tags: grammar

1)''Speaking French while in Paris is ***more like*** a continuous situation than a repeated event ''

can I make the sentence above without the word ''***like***'' in the same meaning?

2)''Speaking French while in Paris is ***more*** a continuous situation than a repeated event ''

Answer (score -1):

yes, and it means the same thing.